# Duplicated table in Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

I think I have exactly the problem described here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250476270?answerId=250909160022#250909160022 - Numbers apparently drawing the spreadsheet on top of itself, offset, for no obvious reason. Presumably I hit the wrong shortcut key and didn't notice at the time.

[image]

I assume the given answer will solve my problem... but I don't understand what it's telling me to do, and I don't seem to be able to add a comment to the thread. What it suggests doing is as follows:

> Select both, then open the format inspector, choose Table and check the Table Names checkbox.
>
> Both tables should have the same name. The duplicate will have " - 1" added to the end.
>
> Afte checking that any recent editing has been done in the origina (and repeating it there if that is not the case)l, delete the duplicate.

This isn't at all clear to me.

How do I "select both"?

I have the format inspector opened... I think... but there is no Table Names checkbox. (Maybe this is due to my failure to "select both"?)

How do I "delete the duplicate"?

(OS 10.14.6, Numbers 10.1 (6913))

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have no idea - the instructions aren't at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

The table is selected by clicking the little circle thing.

[image]

There's no need to fiddle about as suggested in the forum post - just press the Delete key to delete it.